# How should I close and unregister socket registered to a selector

Tags: python, sockets

In my code I am opening a socket which I register to an EpollSelector. The [documentation for selectors/unregister()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#selectors.BaseSelector.unregister) then says that:

> A file object shall be unregistered prior to being closed.

How can I guarantee this with code looking like this:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as a_socket:
    a_socket.bind(socket_addr)
    a_socket.listen(1)

    epoll = select.epoll()
    epoll.register(a_socket, select.EPOLLIN, select.EPOLLERR, select.EPOLLHUP)

    do_stuff()

    epoll.unregister(a_socket)
```

If do_stuff raises an exception how can I make sure the unregister happens before the socket closes? What sort of problems can occur if I don't unregister before closing the socket?

Comment: Could an explicit `try: finally:` around `do_stuff` be an option?

Comment: If you don't use that `epoll` object outside the `with` block, it probably doesn't matter. I think that requirement in the documentation is only relevant if you continue to use the selector.

Comment: Which _documentation then says that

"A file object shall be unregistered prior to being closed"_?

Comment: @Armali: I added a link, but now I read it as "if you unregister, you should do it before closing the file". But I guess it is fine to close it without unregistering it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to wrap the do_stuff() with a try/except?

```
try:
  do_stuff()
except Exception as e:
  print("There was an error!")
epoll.unregister(a_socket)
```